# Not getting Desired Output (Struct with Array) C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct galaxy
{
    int x_pixel;
    int y_pixel;
};

galaxy get_space_ship(int size)
{
    galaxy UFO[size];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        UFO[i].x_pixel = 10;
        UFO[i].y_pixel = 10;
    }
    return UFO[size];
}

galaxy update(galaxy UFO[], int size)
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        UFO[i].x_pixel += 100;
        UFO[i].y_pixel += 100;
    }
    return UFO[size];
}

int main()
{
    galaxy space_ship[10];
    space_ship[10] = get_space_ship(10);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        cout << space_ship[i].x_pixel << endl;
        cout << space_ship[i].y_pixel << endl;
    }
    space_ship[10] = update(space_ship,10);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        cout << space_ship[i].x_pixel;
        cout << space_ship[i].x_pixel;
    }
}
```

Here i am trying to make a program with struct of two fields(x_pixel,y_pixel)for an array and then initialize them and get updated their value and get them printed but not getting the expected output.My code does not have any compilation error.please review my code and let me know where i am wrong and also include some tips since i am newbie.
THANX

Comment: C-style arrays don't support the semantics that you're using them for. Try `std::array`. Alternatively, `std::vector` for non-static sizes.

Comment: `galaxy space_ship[10]; space_ship[10] = ...` - Undefined behavior right here. `space_ship` only has 10 elements, so the valid indices are 0 .. 9.

Comment: Use std::vector!

Comment: `galaxy UFO[size];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must be declared using a constant expression to denote the number of entries, not a variable.  Use `std::vector`, as multiple comments and answers have suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in C does not work like you think they work. They are not first-class citizens so you cannot pass or return them by value. Arrays decay into pointers to their first element instead. It is a good thing since, in your example, you do not want to copy the whole array so many times back and forth. Here is a working example which does what you want:

```
struct galaxy
{
    int x_pixel;
    int y_pixel;
};

void get_space_ship(galaxy* arr, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        arr[i].x_pixel = 10;
        arr[i].y_pixel = 10;
    }
}

void update(galaxy* arr, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        arr[i].x_pixel += 100;
        arr[i].y_pixel += 100;
    }
}

int main()
{
    galaxy space_ship[10];
    get_space_ship(space_ship, 10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << space_ship[i].x_pixel << endl;
        cout << space_ship[i].y_pixel << endl;
    }
    update(space_ship, 10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << space_ship[i].x_pixel;
        cout << space_ship[i].x_pixel;
    }
}
```

C arrays, though, considered a very low-level and bug-prone construct for these very reasons. A better way would be to use std::vector<> or std::array<> and pass them by reference to save copies.

```
std::vector<galaxy> get_space_ship(int size)
{
    std::vector<galaxy> ships;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        ships.push_back(galaxy{ 10, 10 });

    return ships;
}

void update(std::vector<galaxy>& ships) // note reference
{
    for (auto & ship : ships)
    {
        ship.x_pixel += 100;
        ship.y_pixel += 100;
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto ships = get_space_ship(10);

    for (const auto & ship : ships)
    {
        cout << ship.x_pixel << endl;
        cout << ship.y_pixel << endl;
    }

    update(ships);

    for (const auto & ship : ships)
    {
        cout << ship.x_pixel;
        cout << ship.x_pixel;
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need to state size multiple times anymore since you work with a higher level abstraction which knows its size.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to work with arrays decayed to pointers in C++. There are safer and clearer alternatives.

Comment: Well, I was explaining how arrays work, you are saying he/she should not know this?

Comment: Maybe OP should know this, but certainly not use it. Could you add a small sample (eg `get_space_ship`) that works with a reference to an array, and the even better one that returns an (RVO'd) `std::array` or an `std::vector`? I'm sure it would greatly help OP to learn the idiomatic C++ ways to pass arrays around.

Comment: @patatahooligan No probelm, done.

Comment: Looking great! As a side note, you can iterate through the vector as such `for (auto& ship : ships)` and then do `ship.x += 100;` etc. It's equivalent, but cleaner. Only for C++11 or newer, though, but that isn't a problem on most platforms.

Comment: Thanx a lot for suggestion.I am complete newbie.

Comment: @patatahooligan Refactored that too :) Also changed to pre-increment in the regular for-loop since I felt it was going to be the next thing :)

Comment: @mentalprogrammer No problem, would be grateful if you accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have misconceptions about the following c++ constructs:

- `space_ship[10]` does not mean "all ten spaceships". It means the spaceship with index 10 (= eleventh spaceship). You do not have as many spaceships, you have ten.
- if you are not familiar with pointers, steer clear of plain C++ arrays, the have some surprising behavior forcing you to use pointers. Especially it is hard to work with they array as a whole. If you are completely new to C/C++, I suggest using `std::vector` or `std::array` (for fixed number of elements), the will be more predictable for you.
- if you want to keep using regular [] arrays then note that `galaxy_update` does not receive a copy of the array, it directly modifies the array. There is not need to return the modified array.

Suggestion: Definitely indent your code properly. A proper IDE will help you with that. Indenting might seem as a nuisance, but it has big cost/benefits ratio.

Comment: Thanx.looking forward to implents your suggestions.